# Strange rendering after waking up

Tags: ubuntu, laptop

When I try to use my laptop after it was in suspended mode, I get something like that
[image]

GPU is okay as if I reopen the application everything works fine. It happens only with applications based on web and javascript (google chrome, vs code)

Is there any way I can fix it?

Ubuntu 20.10, Xiaomi MI notebook pro. The problem used to happen with Ubuntu 19.10 but after the update to 20.04 it disappeared. But after another update the problem appeared again. On 19.10 it appeared after the attempt to install MacOS on the laptop.

I also have Windows dualboot, it works fine

Comment: If you have an NVIDIA GPU that's expected - just restart the browser.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yeah, I know, but I don't really want to do it every time... is there any solution for it?

Comment: https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/455.38/README/powermanagement.html